# What is the "chef intended" method to perform an action like installing a vagrant plugin?

Tags: bash, shell, chef-infra

TL;DR:

What is the appropriate way to handle chef `execute` blocks when the execution depends upon it being run as, and having the environment of, a specific user?

---

I'm using chef-solo and writing a cookbook to install (among other things) vagrant and multiple vagrant plugins. The command for installing vagrant plugins takes the following form: `vagrant plugin install [plugin-name]`. Attempting this using the following code:

```
execute "Install Vagrant plugin #{plugin}" do
   command "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}"
end
```

...results in the plugin being installed at `/root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/plugin-1.0.0`. Attempting a version that specifies the user to run as:

```
execute "Install Vagrant plugin #{plugin}" do
   user "#{user}"
   group "#{user}"
   command "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}"
end
```

...results in the user `#{user}` not being able to execute the command due to lack of sufficient permissions - the process attempts to install the plugin at `/root/.vagrant.d` instead of `/home/#{user}/.vagrant.d`. I also attempted a further version adding the `environment` directive on top of specifying the user/group:

```
execute "Install Vagrant plugin #{plugin}" do
   environment ({ 'HOME' => ::Dir.home(user), 'USER' => user })
   user "#{user}"
   group "#{user}"
   command "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}"
end
```

...results in the plugin being installed as expected, but I don't believe this is the intended method of handling this class of actions - specifically because this solution only works if the user in question exists at compile time, which in my case, it will not (the user not existing at compile time can be resolved adding `.run_action(:create)` to the portion that creates the user in question).

My understanding is that this involves the question of chef running execute commands as a login or non-login shell, but I'm only barely aware of the difference between the two.

I found a serverfault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/402881/execute-as-vagrant-user-not-root-with-chef-solo) which answered this issue, however the latest activity was over 4 years ago. The old chef issue tracker contained two issues ([CHEF-1523](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1523), [CHEF-2288](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2288)) but I've not been able to find updates to either of these two issues within the new (github based) issue trackers.

What is the chef best practice in these types of situations?

Any tips, hints, or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

- Informatician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would delay the computation of the home dir until converge time:

```
execute "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}" do
  user user
  group user
  environment lazy { {'HOME' => Dir.home(user)} }
end
```

We've talked about automatically setting groups and some common env vars, and I've implemented a helper version in https://github.com/poise/poise/blob/master/lib/poise/utils/shell_out.rb, but it hasn't been backported to Chef core (yet).

Comment: Thanks coderanger, this is very valuable feedback. I wasn't aware of the ability for properties to undergo lazy evaluation. This is something I'll still likely use very sparingly, but it's good to have in ye olde basket of tricks. Many thanks!